# How to do a list of square in GRID XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a grid in XAML by the following:

[GRID Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO1ab.png)

I tried something like this but I have no ideea how to add the red squares.
Do I have to make a grid in grid?

Right now, I have this code

```
<Window x:Class="MonitorComenzi.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MonitorComenzi"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="30" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black">Comenzi plasate</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="30" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Green">Comenzi preparate</TextBlock>
        
    </Grid>
    
</Window>
```

Comment: Use a Grid, UniformGrid or WrapPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make nested Grids, its absolutly fine, but a single StackPanel do the trick as well. Something like this:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="30" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black">Comenzi plasate</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="30" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Green">Comenzi preparate</TextBlock>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Margin="10"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0">

            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="5 0"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="5 0"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="5 0"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="5 0"/>

        </StackPanel>
        
    </Grid>
```

[image]